# synchronising threads with mutex in c

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

my problem is that I create multible threads every thread get a struct which has a int value and i just want to give this int value the value i, and the thread function should print it out but it dont print 1,2,3,4... it print for example 4,3,3,2  , I am already using a mutex

edited:

```
#include "common.h" // there is pthread_mutex_t lock;
#include "threadwork.c"


void *thread_work(void *arg);


int main(void) {

   int workers;
   struct thread_data *thread_array=malloc(sizeof(char)*100000000);
   
   scanf("%d",workers);
   
   if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL)!=0)
 {
       printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
       return 1;
   }
   
   
   
        for(int i =0;i<workers;i++){
//  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
              thread_array->offset=i;
//                printf("server printed i= %d\n",thread_array->offset);

              
      thread_id=pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL,thread_work,thread_array);
//                          pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
       if(thread_id==-1){
           perror("fehler bei thread_id");      
           
       }
       
  }
  
     for(int i =0;i<workers;i++){
    pthread_join (thread[i],NULL);
    
  }

****this above is the main file and under it the threadworkfile****
  
  void *thread_work(void *arg){
   
struct thread_data *rec_data=(struct thread_data *) arg;

 unsigned char chekcsumme=0;
 
 pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

 printf("%d\n",rec_data->offset);

 pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);


 return  (void*)NULL;
};
```

Comment: It looks like you supply the same `thread_data` to all threads and that you change the value of `offset` in that `thread_data` without synchronization. This will lead to undefined behavior. Please show a [mre]

Comment: In C all pointers can be implicitly converted to or from `void *`. The casts in `thread_work` aren't needed.

Comment: And building on the comment by @TedLyngmo, `thread_array->offset=i;` indicates that `thread_array` isn't really an array but a pointer to a single structure object. Which means the variable `thread_array` is rather badly named. If it *is* an array you need to use array indexing to get the proper element.

Comment: thread_array is a struct which contains a offset and and array, yes i know its bad named

Comment: i edited my post I hope you can read it better now, these threads have to work on the array and every structs should work even, for example array with 10 bytes and 5 threads so every thread does 2 bytes from the array, this is the reason why every threads takes the same array, i just want to give them other offsets

Comment: I think I solved my problem more or less  I think i have to use semaphore not mutex

Comment: No, you don't need semaphores. You probably don't even need a mutex here but it's hard to say for sure without a [mre]

Comment: Note that `pthread_create()` does not set `errno`, but instead [returns an error number upon failure](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html#tag_16_424_04). (Unless, perhaps, you're on z/OS and _not_ compiling for SUSv3 compatibility?)